# How to add more cells to dynamically generated html with colspan?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am generating a dynamic table by taking input by user i.e number of row and column, which is working fine, now i need to do is, again taking input from the user to add more column to the specified row. I sticking in approach and what else i can try to reach out the destination. please Help

CS File Code for generating dynamic table:

```
    public void create_table( int row, int col)
        {
            int row = Convert.ToInt32(txtrow.Text);     // No. of Rows
            int col = Convert.ToInt32(txtcol.Text);            
          for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {

                HtmlTableRow rows = new HtmlTableRow();         //a new Row
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                {

                    HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell(); //a new Cell
                    //cell.InnerHtml = i + "," + j;             //Insert Data into Cell
                    cell.Align = "Center";
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    //htmlTable1.Controls.Add(t
                    //create_label(j,i);
                    cell.ID = i + "," + j;
                    rows.ID = Convert.ToString(i);
                    int rowncount = rows.Controls.Count;
                    int columncount = rows.Controls.Count;
                    //lbl1.Text = Convert.ToString();
                    cell.BgColor = "red";
                   // cell.Width = "700px";
                    htmlTable1.Width = "700px";
                    htmlTable1.Border = 0;
                    htmlTable1.CellPadding = 0;
                    htmlTable1.CellSpacing = 5;
                    rows.Cells.Add(cell);
                    // rows.Cells.Add(cell);
                    htmlTable1.Rows.Add(rows);
                    cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    lbl.Text = i + "," + j;
                    lbl.ID = i + "," + j;
                    //cell.InnerHtml = ".";
                }
            }
        }
```

Till now code is working fine but i need to apply, dynamic addition of cells to specific row, row number will be enter by user itself.
Also want to check the width of every td in every "tr" 
New approach is highly appreciated.

```
   NEED Out Put:
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top" width="31">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left" valign="top" width="646"></td>
          <td align="left" valign="top" width="23">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top" width="31" colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a web databound control like `GridView` with a DataSource like a `DataTable`, that makes your life much easier. Also, why do you need the fixed widths?

Comment: I havent use gridview as theres no database included also, the main motive is to genrate a dynamic table, and to get HTML for that table. Reason for having fixed width is that, to populate images in different <td>.

Comment: You don't need a database to be able to use a `GridView` or `DataTable`. However, what is the actual problem? Where did you get stuck? You have mentioned that "till now code is working fine", but what is the difficulty in your new requirement?

Comment: I am stucking in how to approach to meet this requirement. My need is to create a dynamic table and to get the code of the that HTML table. no matter how many rows and column added.

Comment: Just a few consideration about your code 1.Your table style(like color, padding) should be located in CSS file, not in C# code 2. Also it is better to set meaningful name to your htmlTable1 variable

Comment: @ Disappointed : i am giving the value at the runtime, to the <td>. that's y they are in cs file.

Comment: @Nash. htmlTable1 properties(Width, border, cellpadding, cellspacing) look static, not dynamic, so i don't see where it is taken in runtime  ...

Comment: Do you really need html generated by this dynamic table ? If it is ASP.Net maybe you need just put this table inside aspx page ? As a result it will render html you want

Comment: @Disappointed :yeah thanks! but before rendering it, issue is to create a dynamic HTML Table.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to manipulate the table client side. This way you avoid unnecesary communication to the server.
You can achieve it using jquery to manipulate the html, according to the user input.

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/jineeshjohn/2044414) (the code is not mine) where you get the columns and rows that the user enters, and render the table according to that.

Another option is to use a jquery plugin to manipulate the table. There are many of these plugins (from super simple to really complex), your choice will be based depending on your needs and requirements.

Besides searching on google, you can see a list of jquery table manipulation plugins [here at jquery.com](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/table/) and another list [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/).